# AVSpeechSynthesizer Special characters

Tags: ios, emoji, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm using AVSpeechSynthesizer to read a string, but it gives an error if the string has any special characters like a emoji smile.

How toclean the string for special characters but leave support for japanese, chinese ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the NSString method stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet with the *inverted set* of the NSCharacterSet alphanumeric, which will filter out the emoji

So if your string that contains emoji and Chinese characters is called 'textWithEmoji' then

```
NSString *textToSpeak = [textWithEmoji stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
```

'textToSpeak' will be the same text but without emoji, and other no alphanumeric characters

Comment: but i need the chinese, japanese, arabic... characters!

Comment: they are kept too - have you tried this? it worked for me with a sentence of English that included a Chinese radical and an emoji. The resulting text had the emoji removed, but the Chinese character still in place.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.Replace emoji strings with white space.

Note:If you need to highlight the text like UITextView,don't only remove the emoji strings,because
- (void)speechSynthesizer:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance: delegate method will get wrong range.

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];
NSString *text = @"Text with emoji.";    

[text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)
                             options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                          usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                              if ([substring isEmojiString]) {
                                  // If you need highlight text,replace the emoji with white space
                                  for (int i=0; i<substring.length; i++) {
                                      [string appendString:@" "];
                                  }
                              } else {
                                  [string appendString:substring];
                              }
                          }];
```

NSString Category

```
- (BOOL)isEmojiString {

BOOL returnValue = NO;
const unichar hs = [self characterAtIndex:0];
// surrogate pair
if (0xd800 <= hs && hs <= 0xdbff) {
    if (self.length > 1) {
        const unichar ls = [self characterAtIndex:1];
        const int uc = ((hs - 0xd800) * 0x400) + (ls - 0xdc00) + 0x10000;
        if (0x1d000 <= uc && uc <= 0x1f77f) {
            returnValue = YES;
        }
    }
} else if (self.length > 1) {
    const unichar ls = [self characterAtIndex:1];
    if (ls == 0x20e3) {
        returnValue = YES;
    }

} else {
    // non surrogate
    if (0x2100 <= hs && hs <= 0x27ff) {
        returnValue = YES;
    } else if (0x2B05 <= hs && hs <= 0x2b07) {
        returnValue = YES;
    } else if (0x2934 <= hs && hs <= 0x2935) {
        returnValue = YES;
    } else if (0x3297 <= hs && hs <= 0x3299) {
        returnValue = YES;
    } else if (hs == 0xa9 || hs == 0xae || hs == 0x303d || hs == 0x3030 || hs == 0x2b55 || hs == 0x2b1c || hs == 0x2b1b || hs == 0x2b50) {
        returnValue = YES;
    }
}

return returnValue;
```

}